# Where does Chrome gets its list of certificate authorities from?

Tags: fedora, chrome, certificates

On Fedora, I'm talking about the list displayed when you go to settings > manage certificates > authorities tab.

I've read that it should be in the NSS shared DB, but this command returns an empty list:

```
[laurent@localhost nssdb]$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are `NSS` built-in certificates. They are provided through a shared library: `/usr/lib/libnssckbi.so` (path may be different on your system). That's where Chrome gets them from.
You could list them with `certutil` like this:

Make a link to the library in `~/.pki/nssdb`:

```sh
ln -s /usr/lib/libnssckbi.so ~/.pki/nssdb
```

Then run:

```sh
certutil -L -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb/ -h 'Builtin Object Token'
```

Output:

```sh
Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

Builtin Object Token:GTE CyberTrust Global Root              C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:Thawte Server CA                        C,,C 
Builtin Object Token:Thawte Premium Server CA                C,,C 
Builtin Object Token:Equifax Secure CA                       C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:Digital Signature Trust Co. Global CA 1 C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:Digital Signature Trust Co. Global CA 3 C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:Verisign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2 ,C,  
Builtin Object Token:Verisign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2 ,C,C 
Builtin Object Token:Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2 C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:GlobalSign Root CA                      C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:GlobalSign Root CA - R2                 C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:ValiCert Class 1 VA                     C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:ValiCert Class 2 VA                     C,C,C
Builtin Object Token:RSA Root Certificate 1                  C,C,C
..................................................................
..................................................................
```

Comment: And if I want to add a certificate to Chrome's trusted store using certutil, How can I?

certutil -d sql:$home/.pki/nssdb -A -n 'certificate name' -i filename.cer -t "CT,,"

adds the cert into the nss db, but Chrome and Firefox don't see/trust the new cert.

Comment: @ndemarco - your command looks good to me, no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

It get's them from the underlying operating system. You can read about it here:

- [Root Certificate Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy)

*excerpt from above link*

> Google Chrome attempts to use the root certificate store of the
>   underlying operating system to determine whether an SSL certificate
>   presented by a site is indeed trustworthy, with a few exceptions.

That page goes on to describe who to contact if you're a root CA provider for the various OSes etc.

#### References

- [LinuxCertManagement](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement)
- [NSS Shared DB And LINUX](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB_And_LINUX)

Comment: It seems like this has changed in version 1.4 of the policy at the link above (Root Certificate Policy 1.4) "Chrome began a platform-by-platform transition from relying on the host operating system’s Root Store to its own on Windows, macOS, ChromeOS, Linux, and Android."

Answer (score 3):

In the off chance that you're asking because you actually need to use the list of root CAs, here they are (unfortunately named only by index):

### Individual Certificate Files

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas/tree/master/pems

### Mozilla's Big File of Certificates

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1

#### Scripts to Parse the Big File of Certificates

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas

https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/mk-ca-bundle.html

#### General Information about extracting Mozilla's Certificates File

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has changed in Chrome 107 as Google bring in their own "Chrome Root Store"

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/faq.md

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#certVerifRem107